# Is there a Google Sheets function that will return ALL ranges that contain a specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

| Name | Column |
| --- | --- |
| Andy | 1 |
| Carol | 2 |
| Andy | 3 |
| Carol | 4 |
| Andy | 5 |
| Andy | 6 |
| Andy | 6 |

I would like the function
`function(A:A,"Andy")`
to return something like `B2, B4, B6:B8`
Basically, all the cells containing the value `Andy` in the range I've already specified. I've looked in many places and didn't find anything that exactly does this.

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in function that does that, but you could create a custom function. Read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: You can return the indices and re-create the range strings yourself. Try that and if you still have questions, I would include an example sheet with the specific issues you run into. Consult guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal, viable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as needed.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function xfind(x=5) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map((r,i)=>{
    let row = [];
    r.forEach((c,j) => {
      if(c == x) {
        row.push(sh.getRange(i+1,j+1).getA1Notation())
      }
    });
    return row
  }).flat().join(',');
  Logger.log(vs)
  return vs;
}
```

I ran it on a spreadsheet like this:

`=xfind(7)` and it returned the string `L2,O3,P3,O4,D6,J6,T6,D7,L7,B8,D8,K9,H12,O12,C13,K13,E14,J14,E15,H19,R20`

I made no attempt to join consecutive cells into larger ranges.

Comment: This works thanks! I'll probably have to join consecutive cells into larger ranges myself

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A2:B,A2:A="Andy"),,2)
```

[image]

OR
you may need this result

```
=INDEX(ADDRESS(FILTER(A2:B,A2:A="Andy"),2,4),,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Except its incorrect the first one should be B2